# floating headers to two different divs

Tags: html, css

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/MMWXj/1/  I have an "About" section and a "Skills" Section. If you click on the title to either of those sections, there is a drop down that reveals the relevant content. If "About" is open, then it will close if you click to open "Skills." Here "about" has been clicked...

```
 About

   this is About content revealed by click

 Skills
```

And here "Skills" has been clicked

```
About
Skills

this is Skills content revealed by click
```

Instead of having "about" title and "skills" title stacked on top of each other, I'd like them floated side by side, but with the behavior of the content within each div the same,like this (if the skills header has been clicked)

```
About Skills

   this is Skills content revealed by click
```

This is the basic html structure (i've left a few for-the-moment unnecessary bits in out of fear that, once I find the solution to the problem, inserting those bits back in will change things).

I'd be very grateful if you can explain how to achieve that...

```
<div id="who">
    <h1 class="who closed">About</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="latest" class="three_columns">

        <p>
          <strong>Boo!</strong>
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

 <div id="what">
    <h1 class="what closed">Skills</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="consulting" class="three_columns">

        <p>
          <strong>Boo2!</strong>
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

--
CSS

```
div.content { width: 500px; overflow: hidden; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} /* This clears the floats of the child elements, see http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/ */
div.three_columns { float: left; width: 290px; margin: 0px; padding: 10px;  }

#latest{
    padding-left: 30px;
}

/* General headline styles */
/*h1 { font-size: 40px; margin: 0px; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; }
h2 { font-size: 16px; }*/

h1.who, h1.what, h1.how {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;

}

h2.who, h2.what, h2.how {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.blue { color: #00b9f1; }
.green { color: #99cc00; }

/* General link styles - Colors: pink #ec008b, blue #00b9f1, dark gray #222, light gray #ebebeb; */
/*a { color: #222222; text-decoration: none; }
h1.hover, a:hover { color: #ec008b; cursor: pointer; }
h1.active, a:active { color: #00b9f1; cursor: pointer; }*/

/* General list styles */
ul { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
ul li { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style: none; }


#cent {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:
}

/*** Styles for the main content sections ***/
div#who, div#what, div#how { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

JS

```
$(function() {

    // Hide all closed sections
    $(".closed").next().hide();

    // Add slide functions to all sections (h1 elements)
    $("h1").click(function () {
        if($(this).is('.closed')) {
            $(".open").delay(200, function() { $(this).next().slideUp("slow"); });
            $(this).delay(200, function() { $(this).next().slideDown("slow"); });
            $("h1").deactivateElement();
            $(this).activateElement();
        }
        else if($(this).is('.open')) {
            $(this).delay(200, function() { $(this).next().slideUp("slow"); });
            $(this).deactivateElement();
        }
    });

    // Add a function to toggle the CSS styles
    $("a#style_switcher").click(function () { flag = !flag; dark.disabled = flag; });

    // Add hover functions to all sections (h1 elements)
    $("h1").hover(function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); }, function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); });


    // Delay the call to (slide) functions
    // => http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-delay-plugin/
    $.fn.delay = function(time, callback) {
        jQuery.fx.step.delay = function() {};
        return this.animate( { delay: 1 }, time, callback);
    }

    // Set an element class to 'open' or 'closed'
    $.fn.activateElement = function() { switchClasses($(this), 'open', 'closed'); }
    $.fn.deactivateElement = function() { switchClasses($(this), 'closed', 'open'); }

    // Do this at start
    initialize();
    $(".who").delay(600, function() { $(this).next().slideDown("slow"); });
    $(".who").activateElement();
});


// Initialization function
function initialize () {
    flag = true;
    dark = document.getElementById("dark_css");
    dark.disabled = flag;

    // Set year in copyright section
    document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = (new Date()).getFullYear();
}

// Utility function for switching/toggling classes
function switchClasses (element, classToAdd, classToRemove) {
    element.addClass(classToAdd);
    element.removeClass(classToRemove);
    // De/Activate the given element
    (classToAdd == 'open') ? element.addClass('active') : element.removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want tabs.  I would recommend using an existing plugin for tabs. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ Very simple to implement and you can fill them with whatever content you want.

Comment: @Torr3nt thanks for your answer (can't comment directly on your post for some reason)  but, as with one of the other solutions, once you click on the title, it reverts back to its original http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/MMWXj/9/  For example, click "about" and you'll see "skills" appear below the about content. Can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last and First CSS class to this:

```
/*** Styles for the main content sections ***/
div#who, div#what, div#how 
{ 
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   float:left; // new
}

div.content 
{ 
   position:absolute; //new
   width: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Edited!

Comment: that works fine, but once I click one of the titles, it reverts back to its original. Can that be fixed? http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/MMWXj/8/

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't keep the same functionality...http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/MMWXj/12/

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Answer edited again. Is this what you'r want? if not, explain more.

Comment: no, it's not. The h1 "About" and "Skills" should never move but in your answer if you click on the title, they reposition...

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Edited. Now it's working for me fine. just change that two css classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), sound like the functionality you are looking for.

Here is an example of what you might restructure your HTML to work with jQuery Tabs:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#who">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#what">Skills</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="who">
    <div class="content">
      <div id="latest" class="three_columns">

        <p>
          <strong>Boo!</strong>
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- #who -->
  <div id="what">
    <div class="content">
      <div id="consulting" class="three_columns">
        <p>
          <strong>Boo2!</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- #what -->
</div><!-- .tabs -->
```